# Como puedo comprobar que un patrón esta contenido en una palabra en C++?

Tags: c++, string

Resulta que la función del ejercicio es leer de teclado una cadena de palabras y un patrón, y posteriormente mostrar en pantalla aquellas palabras de la cadena que contienen dicho patrón. Por ejemplo: "re" esta contenido en "creo".

Este es mi código pero no se como completarlo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string FINTEXTO="fin";

void procesar (string patron, string texto)
{
    for (int i=0; i<int(patron.size()); ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<int(texto.size()); ++j)
        {
            if(patron[i]==texto[j])
            {
                
            }
        }
    }

}

void leerdatos (string& patron, string& texto)
{
    cout<<"Introduzca el patron en minusculas: ";
    cin>>patron;

    cout<<"Introduzca el texto en minúsculas hasta (fin): ";
    cin>>texto;

    cout<<"Resultado: "<<endl;
    while (texto!=FINTEXTO)
    {
        cin>>texto;
        procesar(patron,texto);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    string patron,texto;
    leerdatos(patron,texto);
}
```

Comment: Hola podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que cambiaría es en el while del main:

lo pondría de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
while (texto!=FINTEXTO)
{
    procesar(patron,texto);
    cin>>texto;
}
```

ya que lo primero que quieres es procesar la palabra que te han pasado, una vez hecho eso la función que buscas es la siguiente:

```cpp
void procesar (string patron, string texto)
{
    if(patron.size() > texto.size()){
        cout << patron << " no esta dentro de " << texto << endl;
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<int(texto.size()); ++i)
    {
        bool coincide = true;
        int var = i;
        for (int j=0; j<int(patron.size()) && coincide; ++j,++var)
        {
            if(patron[j] != texto[var])
            {
                coincide = false;
            }
            
        }

        if(coincide){ //Si sigue es que la ultima iteración (ultima letra) coincide
            cout << patron << " esta dentro de " << texto << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    
    cout << patron << " no esta dentro de " << texto << endl;
}
```

De forma que si una letra difiere se saldría del bucle y buscaría a partir de la siguiente letra

EDIT: arreglado el fallo

Comment: Tu código no funciona como esperas.. ¿Has probado a ejecutarlo?

Comment: Creo que ya lo he solucionado, he editado la respuesta, ya debería de funcionar correctamente, ahora sí que hice más pruebas ya que antes no pude, gracias por avisar

Answer (score 0):

```
void procesar (string patron, string texto)
{
   char *token = strtok(texto, " ");

   while (token)
   { 
       if (strstr(token, patron) != NULL)
       {
          cout << patron << " esta dentro de " << token << endl;
       }

       token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```

Aquí vas a hacer uso de la **función strtok** para separar el texto entrado en **tokens** o palabras independientes atendiendo a un delimitador especificado (que en este caso es " ").

Por cada **token** o palabra se usará la **función strstr** para saber si el patrón está contenido dentro de ese **token**, de estarlo se imprime que ese patrón está dentro de la palabra, de no estarlo no se hace nada.